# Correct way to use mysql database in multiple php files

Tags: php, mysql

HI everyone, I was just wondering what the best way to make multiple queries against tables in a mysql databases is. Should I be making a new mysqli object for every different .php page ($mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "db");)?

Or is there a way to reuse this one time over all php files in my website? Any suggestions would be pretty cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote would be to take an OOP approach. I would have one script that has a DB conn class in it and a method in that class to check if a connection exists and if it does returns the connection object. You could have that db class script referenced [ **include_once();** ] on the pages that need to access the database. Then it would be a matter of instantiating the db object, firing the "if-exists" method and if it returns true then just utilize the existing connection within the object.

You could also take a look at utilizing persitent connections to the DB

[Persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

However honestly you will be better off in the long run and scalability of your application to handle the db connection management yourself rather then leaving a connection constantly open.

Here is an example of how I would structure that class:

**As a note, made by @alex, the mysql_error() should not be echoed to the page in an environment where the display_errors() is set to display all warnings. (e.g error_reporting(E_WARNING);)**

```
class dbconn {
protected $database;

function __construct(){
    $this->connect();
}

protected function connect() {
    $this->database = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass')  or die("<p>Error connecting to the database<br /><strong>" . mysql_error() ."</strong></p>" );
    mysql_select_db('databasename') or die("<p>Error selecting the database<br />" . mysql_error() . "</strong></p>");
}

function __destruct(){
    mysql_close($this->database);
}

function db(){
     if (!isset($this->database)) { 
        $this->connect(); 
     }
     return $this->database;
  }

  }
```

Comment: That is the most brilliant database connection class I have ever seen.

Comment: @Inotekka Serious? What if there is an error connecting to the database. It will echo that potentially dangerous information, with no sort of global flag to disable it.

Comment: again, what sort of dangerous info could be dumped?

Comment: @astgeorge They may know your host and username if it can't create the connection. Generally you want to keep that information hidden. Plus `die()` on error isn't very gracious.

Comment: @alex - ok you have a point on the die() as not being very elegant so that could be altered but even if it was the connection that failed mysql_error does not dump the connection string data, it gives a line number and a failed connection status. Can you accurately identify a time when a mysql_error dumps sensitive data?

Comment: It should not echo anything on error, if `display_errors` is set to `false`, which is a must on production servers. And that information should be logged rather than silently ignored by prefixing with `@` or something like that, as there might be also other (unexpected) errors involved, e.g., `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect`. Have had this once with PHP/Oracle - it took a while to find out why I see no output and no errors logged after migrating to fresh server. Had to leave that `@` prefix though, as user/pass were entered by users...

Comment: @binary, correct and even when display_errors are on it dumps the text of the error message of the last MySQL function. So for example if you had a bad database name or table it might dump:

1049: Unknown database 'nonexistentdb'
1146: Table 'thetable.nonexistenttable' doesn't exist

but then those dont even exist in the database from the get go.

Comment: @astgeorge `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'my-host'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` They now know your username and host.

Comment: @alex - ok good point, the mysql_error() shouldn't be dumped in a environment where display_errors are set to display warnings. I will add that as a note to my post. Would you agree however that its better to check an existing connection in an object then to do as your post said and create the connection for each page?

Comment: @astgeorge Your class creates a connection per page as well, if we are defining page as a request by a user.

Comment: @alex, no it doesn't the protected property $dbc stores the connection. When a page is requested and the object has to be instantiated then the object is created each time not the database connection, see the function db().

Comment: If I would create ultimate DB wrapper, I would forget about `display_errors` and would not use `die`. Actions that are being taken should not depend on value of `display_errors` - it's just a config value that specifies if error messages are printed or not - irreplaceable for development, lethal for production. And `die` is not a good outcome, as it's not a `dbconn` that should decide whether user should see an error message or execution of script should silently stop. The code that uses `dbconn` class is what has to decide it.

Comment: @a.stgeorge, that protected `$dbc` is object property, not class property. For new object, it's value is `NULL` initially.

Comment: @Mike, no problem, sorry for the massive comment debate that ensued.

Comment: I have a question e.x: I have a class for a table and I require_once the dbconnection class in every class of table. Some table class need to require_once few other table class for reference validation and I used this and I got an error user has exceed max_user_connections. Any solution or I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the connection for each page, as each PHP script's lifetime is that of the request.

However, you can place the connection code in one file and then `include` it from all pages.

Comment: You could use [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) though.

Comment: @NullUserException You are right. But I thought I'd keep it simple as the OP doesn't seem to be very experienced.

Comment: @alex. I dont think connection on each page is a good approach. include is a good approach

Comment: @alex. Bro I am also pointing to your second point. That your second point is more feasible than first one.

Comment: @alex the OP mentions referencing the object so he/she must have some OOP experience. However Persistent connections are really not a good road to go down, its like PDO, it allows the programmer to get lazy in handling the connections

Comment: @Awais Qarni They are not related; including the file is still creating the `mysqli` object once per page.

Comment: @all you will have to instantiate the object per page but that isnt the question. The question was is there a need to create a new connection every time and the answer is no, you check for an existing connection object (via the code example posted) and do not recreate a connection to the db.

Comment: @a.stgeorge, persistent connections is a way of optimization, as creating new connection to DB is quite expensive, and there's also no point in holding connection for the whole lifetime of script execution if connection is really needed only for less than 50% of script's lifetime.

Comment: @astgeorge I believe that interpretation of the question is different to mine.

Comment: @binary creating connections are only expensive if you fail to close them when you are done with them.

Comment: @a.stgeorge, no, failing to close is not expensive - it will just lead to reaching "Too many connections" error. And making new connection **is** much more expensive than taking connection from existing connection pool. That's the main reason why there are persistent connections. Though, if you're creating personal blog that gets like 1000 hits per day, you shouldn't really notice it ;)

Comment: @astgeorge `mysql_close()` generally isn't required as the connection is closed when your script finishes executing.

Comment: @binary what if the "connection pool" is limited as many mysql servers are set to 250 conn's then after just a few hundred visitors making requests that query the DB you have exhausted said pool. However I do agree that in the event of no limit on connections this point is mute.

Comment: @alex, ok good point in freeing resources mysql connections are generally closed at the end of a script execution but it is without doubt best practice to manage your resources and ensure the connection is closed.

Comment: @a.stgeorge, as far as I know, with connection pool it's quite difficult to reach even 50 connections with thousands of concurrent users, if pool works as it should.

Comment: @alex, although it's stated that resources are freed automatically, I have had weird problems (error messages regarding DB resources) in the past when not using `mysql_free_result()`. They did not appear everywhere where DB is used, rather in some specific places. After adding `mysql_free_result()` they disappeared.

Comment: @binary - well i dunno i think it would be pretty simple to build a script that creates a new connection every-time and hits that pool limit very fast.Would be an interesting experiment.

Comment: @a.stgeorge, connection pool works like this - it holds number of opened connections; when you request a connection, it either gives you opened connection, or creates new one; when you release a connection, it gets stored into the pool, so it can be used on another request. So if you have 50 connection requests per second with each connection being "reserved" for 20ms, it's actually enough with 1 pooled connection to satisfy every request for connection.

Comment: @binary, good explanation and I understand your point I guess I had meant to say that there can be a scenario in which you don't end a script yet create many connections AND do not close the db manually. I will accept however THAT would be really bad practice and you are right in that it is unlikely to happen :)

Comment: @a.stgeorge, for long-running scripts, persistent connections are even better, as it's possible to use many connections per single page request without having overhead of creating many **new** connections. For example, page generates 1000ms (heavy calculations, GD stuff etc), from which you need DB only 10 times for about 100ms in total - there's no point in holding DB connection for 1000ms in this case (as 90% of time the connection would be just wasted), but there's also no point in creating 10 **new** connections. This is where connection pool saves us resources.

Comment: Will it persistent for each pages of the web app? In core php?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `connect.php` that validates it's being included by **your** application, and then creates a DB connection.

You could then include that file at the beginning of your application's init, or the beginning of any independent script that needs a connection =)

Answer (score -1):

Depends on structure of website. If you have:

```
<a herf='login.php'>login</a>
<a herf='register.php'>register</a>
<a herf='about.php'>about</a>
```

..., then you'll have to connect in every PHP file, i.e., in `login.php`, in `register.php` and in `about.php`. To make it easier, I would either create `config.php` file which holds user/pass, or even do like [Shad said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190758/correct-way-to-use-mysql-database-in-multiple-php-files/5190792#5190792).

---

You might also have `index.php` that contains something like this:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['module']) ) {
    $_GET['module'] = 'about';
}
switch ( $_GET['module'] ) {
    default:
    case 'about':
        include 'about.php';
        break;
    case 'login':
        include 'login.php';
        break;
    case 'register':
        include 'register.php';
        break;
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<a herf='?module=login'>login</a>
<a herf='?module=register'>register</a>
<a herf='?module=about'>about</a>
```

In this case you can connect in `index.php` and then pass the connection to all other involved files.

---

The 2nd way seems to be more common to me, i.e., it feels more intuitive, more handy and that's what I always do.

I believe that in some cases it might be worthy (performance-wise) to use persistent connections and reserve/release connection when needed (either for transaction or even for single query). For example, simple system that I'm now working with takes 70ms-100ms to generate, and it takes only 40ms-50ms to do SQL queries. If using "single connection" approach, it means that connection is wasted for about 50% of time, while "reserve/release connection when needed" with persistent connections would not have such issue.

One more thing - I would advise you to create some wrapper, i.e., some `DBConnection` class that connects to DB in constructor and has methods like `select()` (returns array of data), `selectValue()` (returns single value, e.g., `$db->selectValue('select count(*) from user')` would return `(int)$numberOfUsers`), some `exec()` for inserts and updates etc.

Comment: got to be honest here I am not sure what you are trying to show with your snippet.

Comment: And would that be a reason for down-vote? What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I didn't down vote you I just said I didn't understand it. The question was about creating a database connection on each page load but in your snippet you show nothing about a database connection its just a switch to include different pages that may or may not have a connection present.

Comment: @a.stgeorge, I didn't really understand what author means by having many PHP files. I, for example, currently have ~100 PHP files in my system, 15 of them need a direct access to DB. Author might have either similar structure as I have (in this case it's enough with 1 place to connect to DB, e.g., common `index.php` file) or the one like in 1st snippet that I gave (in that case he needs a way to create connection from many places in code, as there is probably no common initialization script).

Comment: @binary ahh yah i get you now so the idea is to step through the switch and include the script that has the db conn active. I suppose that could be a functional method as well, still however I didnt vote you down! :( but I could vote you up to nullify it you know now that I get what you meant ;)

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you vote up or don't. I just don't get why I got a down-vote ;)

Comment: yah you know its funny a few times I have posted a correct answer for a person and they downvote simply cause they dont like the outcome of the answer or because it means they might need to do something different.